# How do I Access an Already Existing View Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to move from one view controller to the next, using code. I have this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewController2 animated:YES];
```

This code is used in the first screen that launches. I want it to push (under a certain condition) to the NEXT view controller which is called ViewController2. ViewController2 already exists (its a storyboard project). But the current view controller doesn't know what ViewController2 is in the above code. How do I 'get' or 'access' ViewController2? It already exits, with .h and .m files, but how do I call to it!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using storyboards, you can just access it through its identifier like this:

```
ViewController2 *viewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
```

Make sure to properly set its identifier to "ViewController2" or whatever name makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I can't get it to work. I set the identifier and put this code in the implementation of viewController2 but it says use of undeclared identifier "self". So It doesn't know what the storyboard is? Do I need to instantiate that somehow/somewhere?

Comment: which method are you trying to call this in and also which class? The only reason I can see if complaining about "self" is if it is not in a UIViewController subclass or you are trying to do this in a static method.

Comment: Ok, sorry - I fixed the "self" error, but its still not working! So I'm trying to get ViewController1 to move to ViewController2. So In ViewController2 I have: ViewController2 *viewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController2 animated:YES];  but I get an error that says 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0xa1381a0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ViewController2', but yet I did set the identifier in the attributes inspector.

Comment: make sure storyboard id is "ViewController2" in the view controller attributes. Also if you're trying to push from vc1 - vc2, this code should go in vc1 (not sure if you had a typo above).

Comment: THANK YOU! IT Works!! I have been trying to get this all day.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the way that you normally push a view controller when you're using storyboards. You should have a push segue set up in IB and the use performSegueWithIndentifier:sender: to go to the next controller. You should also implement prepareForSegue:sender: where you can get access to both the source and destination controllers. This is the method where you typically provide any data needed for the second view controller to do its job.

Comment: I was simplifying the situation, but the whole story is I'm trying to bypass a terms and conditions screen that is only seen at first launch. So I set up a whole NSUser Defaults key and a conditional statement, but all I need to know is how to conditionally push to the next view. I have all the code to do what I want except how to refer to the next view controller.